# Mysterious scroll-base-color style added at runtime in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 - haven't checked IE6 - I havbe a legend element that shows up blue instead of white as it does in all other browsers.  In IE's web developer toolbar, the color seems to be being set because of a scroll-base-color style setting.  The trouble is that I've never heard of that style setting.  I'm certainly not using it.

When I trace the style, it chooses the html element's css definition.  I've tried overwriting it using something like this:

html, body, fieldset, legend {scroll-base-color: #FFFFFF !important;}

...doesn't work.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

`scroll-base-color` is a nonstandard CSS property supported only by Internet Explorer and Opera. Try

```
html {
    scroll-base-color: #fff;
}
```

To get it to normal.

Comment: Huh. I don't know what the problem is then. Does it look right (without any "fixes") in IE8 or IE9 beta?

Comment: looks fine in FF3.5, Chrome, IE8+ - only see the bug currently in IE7...haven't checked IE6

Comment: Well, I don't know what to do then. Dive into the black art of IE workarounds, I guess. Good luck, sorry I can't help.